# Speech To Text in Safari for iphone using Angular

Tags: ios, angular, google-chrome, safari, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to build a Progressive Web Application (PWA) using angular framework and I am trying include functionality for speech to text. I scouted over the internet and I am not able to find anything that would help me to implement speech to text functionality in Safari, for Iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Try integrate annyang (speech recognition library) within your Angular project

Save the library js file within the application. You can save it to an asset folder.Also, you have to add the js file path within angular.json file.Now, you can directly access library options/callbacks within a component class.

Comment: I tried annyang from iphone 11 and it says that the browser is not supported.